# My website is having trouble implementing external CSS, but was working fine with internal CSS. What is the issue with my code?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to convert my internal CSS code to external CSS code. I created a separate folder called "css" and added a file called "styles.css". I, then, copy and pasted over my body and horizontal rule styles over from my "index.html" to the "styles.css" in hope to making it an external CSS code. I expected that my website would change back to what it was with the internal CSS code, but it reverted back to a website without any CSS codes whatsoever. There was no error messages as well. I tried scanning the code for any error with my own eyes and to no avail, there was no change that I saw fit that would lead me to the goal I was searching for. Here are the codes I implemented for my website. If you need more information to help me, please ask and I will be glad to share as much as I could. Thank You.

[My "index.html" file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMOwm.jpg)

[My "styles.css" file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6QVP.jpg)

[My website(First Time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg3s5.jpg)

Comment: Code in external resources are not allowed in StackOverflow. Please add the code directly in your question itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go up one level by preceding your css path file with `../` and then navigate to your css folder where you can access the css file.

Change this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
```

To this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the CSS from the same directory as your HTML.

Try `<link href="/css/[name of stylesheet].css" rel="stylesheet" />`